# How to split a java class file (.java)

Tags: java, file, class, split, project

In my project I have many classes with many subclasses inside it, so I wanted to split them in multiple .java files like other projects that I've seen
For example the miglayout open source project, there are a class named MigPane.java, and it look like it's splitted on multiple files (MigPane$subClassName.java, MigPane$subClassName2.java).

How to do like that please ?.
Sorry for my bad english.
Thank you.

Comment: There is no such thing. You mean `.class` files, not `.java` files. `MigPane$subClassName2.java` means the class inside would have to be named `MigPane$subClassName2`.

Comment: You Can transfer all data in Class file into a text file and then split it.

Comment: If you have .java files that contain inner classes, the compiler will automatically create multiple files when you compile your code.

Answer (score 1):

When you see class files, such as `MigPane$subClassName.class` it is a result of `MigPane` containing an inner class named `subClassName`.  The compiler automatically compiles such a class from one source named `MigPane.java` to two separate files.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do it. These multiple files that you are seeing in your directory or project ( like `MigPane$subClassName.class`) are basically the inner classes (e.g. `subClassName`) defined within the `MigPane.java` class. These nested classes are somehow linked with the enclosed classes , So you can't segregate them.

Comment: @Sajjad-I have put the comment in your that question.. Have a look at that.